# CakePHP 2.6.7: How to block website access when updating

Tags: php, cakephp

Sorry about my English is not good enough so I don't know how to search it.

As the title, I want to block website when I update new data (such as: source code or database).

I have tried to make index.html file and upload into host but website still access to index.php.
I have also tried to rename or delete index.php file. Not successful too !

So that the reason why I made the question to ask you about this.

Summary: How can I block or stop user access website when I am updating it?

Comment: You can create one `index.html` file with under maintenance label and set highest priority to that file from your server.

Comment: `also tried to rename or delete index.php file. Not successful too !` what file did you edit/delete? The simplest way to do what you're asking is to modify `app/webroot/index.php`. e.g. put this at the top of if `<?php require "maintainance.html"; exit;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create index.html file in your App/webroot with the 'maintenance' message.

Then in your AppController::beforeFilter method

```
if($this->request->clientIp() != 'YOUR IP ADDRESS') {
    $this->redirect('/index.html');
}
```

YOUR IP ADDRESS can be on localhost **::1** or **127.0.0.1**, on remote host use your real ip   http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/

With this approach, you can still access your web application, but everyone else will see the index.html page.

Comment: Modifying the *application code* each time you need to do a maintenance task is not a nice way to do this. Also automating this in a deploy script is awkward.

Comment: @Salines: I understand your method about it. I try to do and succeed. Thank for your answes.

Answer (score 2):

Blocking is not a nice the way to go from a user perspective. Usually you want to avoid down times.

Just [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) your most recent version of your website to your live folder:

```
/var/www/myfancysite -> /var/data/myfancysite-20151010121212
```

Do a fresh checkout in a *new* folder `myfancysite-<datetime>` of the site and make a copy of the DB as well. Apply DB migrations as needed and just switch the symlink to the folder with the new time stamp at the end. You'll have zero downtime in an ideal case. And on top you can rollback pretty quickly  to your last version in the case something went wrong: Just restore the symlink to the previous version.

If you still have to add some maintenance screen just change the symlink to a folder with a temporary site:

```
/var/www/myfancysite -> /var/data/myfancysite-maintenance
```

This can be *fully* automated with deploy scripts as well so that you don't have to do it manually like `deploy <site>` and `deploy rollback <site>`.

Some tools that will help with these tasks:

- http://deployer.org/
- https://github.com/Codegyre/Robo

Comment: Thank for your answer but I am too stupid to understand, I think that I will take your answer as the note and research in future. Now I need to solve my task right now. Thank you again.